# How to use launch commands in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Okay, well, I want to make something like OS... But when I start the `.bat` file there's a `set` option for going to help and going to the GUI. I have shortcut with `-gsys32` - directly to boot the command. Brhfd... Just take a look if the code, I leave some comments.

```
@ECHO off
echo GraphicalSystem
echo All rights reserved! 2016
echo PLEASE WRITE help TO OPEN THE HELP WINDOW!

set /p command=

if %command% ==help goto help

if %command% ==gsys32 goto interface

cmd /k
:help
cls
echo gsys32 - Open the graphical interface.
echo exithelp - exit the help
set /p command=

if %command% ==exithelp goto start

cmd /k
:interface
cls
color 17
@ECHO OFF


echo PROGRAMS - GSYS32

echo DRIVE A:\
dir
@ECHO OFF
echo *Write dir /name of the directory without the slashes/*

cmd /k
:start
cls
@ECHO off
echo GraphicalSystem
echo All rights reserved! 2016
echo PLEASE WRITE help TO OPEN THE HELP WINDOW!

set /p command=

if %command% ==help goto help

if %command% ==gsys32 goto interface // I want this to be executed with the shortcut.

cmd /k
```

And now the shortcut:
[image: This is an image]

So... I want the command from the screenshot to be executed in the code...

Comment: `-gsys32` is what you need to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be just a section of the code, so it's difficult to tell.

```
set "command=%1"
if not defined command goto noparms
if /i "%command%"=="gsys" goto interface
if /i "%command%"=="help" goto help
echo parameter "%1" not recognised&pause
rem don't know what you want to do now...
...
:noparms
rem there were no parameters supplied
....your posted code
```

`%1` accesses the first parameter supplied to the routine.

you would need `-gsys` in place of `gsys` if you want to detect `-gsys` as a parameter. The match is literal (`/i` option makes it case-insensitive)

It is windows convention that switch-parameters use the format `/gsys` - but that's a convention, not a rule.

`set /p "var=Promptstring"` is the general form for accepting keyboard input. Parameters are read using `%1`..`%9`

Comment: I don't get it... I have `cmd /k` and it closes after 1 milesecond... but i opened it so much times and taked a screenshot... The line says: `="gsys" is unexpected at this time` or something like that.. HALP!1!!!!11!

Comment: I goofed. The comparison operator is `==`, not `=`